# Using std::atomic for once-only execution

Tags: android, c++, multithreading, std

I'm using a piece of code like this to execute something only once:

```
class Test {
public:
    void foo() {
        if (m_barrier.exchange(true)) {
            return;
        }

        // This should only execute once
    }
private:
    std::atomic<bool> m_barrier { false };
};
```

The function `foo` is called by multiple threads, multiple times, but the code below the `exchange` should only execute once (per object instance).

I thought this was correct code - until yesterday I discovered that sometimes the code below `exchange` executes more than once.

This is on Android, CPU aarch64, so possibly an Android specific bug in `std`, it happened on three different phones - or more likely I'm missing something and the code does not guarantee once-only execution?

Please don't suggest using `std::once`, I can't use it here because of... reasons.

Updated: yes I could replace it with `std::mutex` and a non-atomic `bool`, that's understood, the question is why is `std::atomic` not thread safe.

Comment: Looks correct to me. Maybe a bug somewhere else, e.g. something writing out-of-bounds over `m_barrier`?

Comment: The `m_barrier` member is not static, you might just have the function called from multiple objects

Comment: Not the answer you want but you'd probably be better off to synchronize access to `m_barrier` with a regular `std::mutex` and a `std::scoped_lock`.

Comment: @WBuck -- `m_barrier` is **atomic**; it has well-defined semantics when accessed from multiple threads. Yes, you could replace it with a much heavier synchronization object, but there's nothing in the question (so far) that indicates that that's appropriate.

Comment: @TheDreamsWind -- the question says that the function is supposed to be called **once per object**. Making `m_barrier` static wouldn't do that.

Comment: @PeteBecker Sorry, I didn't mention it but the idea would be to take `m_barrier` a regular, non-atomic `bool`. No point in paying the the cost of sequential consistency if you're using a `std::mutex` anyway

Comment: @PeteBecker I'd want to see bench marks comparing the traditional approach (`std::mutex`) to an `atomic` using a sequentially consistent memory ordering. If there is high lock contention in the OP's use case then I'd suspect the `atomic` could be faster. But if there isn't high lock contention I suspect the `std::mutex` to be faster. But again, this would need to be benchmarked to know for sure.

Comment: If any thread relies on any side effects of the code that comes after the test you've got a data race. `std::once` guarantees that every thread that calls the once-function will see all side effects of the once-function and the correct return value. This code doesn't guarantee either. Don't know if that's a problem in the intended use of this function, but it's certainly a potential trap.

Comment: Not to mention, a lot less cognitive overhead using a regular lock.

Comment: @WBuck -- really? You need a benchmark to see that locking a mutex, reading and possibly changing a value, and unlocking the mutex takes longer than atomically reading and possibly changing a value?

Comment: @PeteBecker can you clarify the "this code doesn't guarantee either" - are you talking about my original snippet?

Comment: @KostyaVasilyev -- yes. For example, if the code following the test writes to a non-atomic member of `Test`, any code that reads the member after calling `foo()` creates a data race. The write and the subsequent reads are not synchronized. Think of it as the first thread sets the barrier then the OS immediately puts that thread to sleep, before it executes the "should only execute once" code. Another thread sees that the barrier has been set, so it happily proceeds to do its thing, even though the "should only execute once" code has not been executed.

Comment: @PeteBecker thank you, understood. But no issues with the "once" aspect, correct?

Comment: @KostyaVasilyev -- looks okay to me.

Comment: @PeteBecker But let's be clear here. Given the choice between an application that runs a bit slower but produces the correct answer and an application that runs faster but produces the wrong answer, I'd choose the former option 100% of the time. So unless you have a solution to the OP's question my suggestion stands. And of course intuitively I'd think a `std::mutex` would be slower but I never go by just my intuition because your intuition may be wrong.

Comment: @WBuck — now you’re reaching. You have no idea what the actual problem is, and no way of knowing that using a mutex would fix it.

Comment: Leave Test as it is but delete  it's  copy/move constructor and assign operator and try to run it. If you get an error that constructor /operator not defined that might be an answer.